# python subprocess console output - eclipse calls batch calls python calls exe

Tags: python, eclipse, windows, batch-file, subprocess

I have the situation that I want the job done from eclipse so I use **eclipse's .launch configuration**. I tried to make it run **python directly** but got error:  `error 193 (%1 is not a valid Win32 app)`. where %1 is probably my python script.

I decided to create a simple **batch script** that calls this big wild **python** animal.

I did a lot of combinations and found this the best (batch outputs some strings, runs python, waits for it, the outputs some strings again):

```
start /b /wait "Python_script.py" "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5"
```

It worked until python itself started to run exe file.

Once again I tried a lot of combinations:

`os.system([exe, arg1, arg2, ...])` and
`subprocess.call(..)` and `subprocess.check_output(..)`

-> I either didn't see the output in eclipse console, or the output was delayed or there was only python / or only exe's output in console.

finally I used `subprocess.Popen(...)` and it's nearly allright - the only defect is that the output from python script don't wait for exe's process to finish, and **when I use `subprocess.Popen(...).wait()` exe passes output to console but the WHOLE output from python script is delayed until the 'exe' terminates**. I want to delay only the part of pythons script output that is written after the exe is called.

- how to achieve this 'partly console output delay' is the main topic
- advices on python and eclipse .launch configuration will be appreciated
- general advices on how does the communication between this processes(?) work will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, Eclipse runs the process with piped stdin and stdout. Some programs buffer their output when stdout is a pipe or file. You can run `python.exe -u python_script.py ...` to at least prevent Python from buffering its stdout.

Comment: Try with `start "" /b /wait "Python_script.py" "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4" "%5"` (note the additional `""`); otherwise the `start` command might interprete the first (quoted) string as a window title rather than a program (which was `"Python_script.py"` in your case)...

Comment: The -u option worked for me !!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have three different processes you're trying to get to work together, you've tried a whole bunch of stuff to get it working, and the code is complex enough that you can't easily post it here.  That makes it pretty hard to get a good answer (Stack Overflow works much better with focused questions), but here's the general approach I'd take:

1. Does your script run if you try to run `Python_script.py` directly from the command prompt?

   - If it doesn't, then look into registering the .py file type in Windows.
   - If it does, then maybe Eclipse launch configurations don't support or don't properly support Windows registered file types. There should be no need to mess with batch files and `start`; just replace `Python_script.py` in your launch configuration with `c:\Python27\python.exe Python_script.py` (or similar).
2. Get your script working from a command prompt - able to run, with proper Python and subprocess output, and waiting for everything to terminate.
3. If things work from the command prompt and still don't work from Eclipse, then post a new question with a small snippet of code showing what you're trying and a description of what's wrong. `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.check_output`, and `Popen` all have different uses, so it's hard to give general advice besides just [referring to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: 1. It does. I tried what eryksun has proposed in a comment so in eclipse launch config I placed sth like this 'C:\Python34\python.exe C:\path_to_script\Python_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3' but the output was as when I call batch calling python - not as desired.
'\n'
2. This scripts works properly when I run it directly from CMD: "python Python_script.py arg1 arg2 arg3" or "python arg1 arg2 arg3" (so the wait function causes python script to wait until exe terminates, but it doesn't delay script's output from before the exe was called.